# Spring Security access denied roles or what else?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to make my application working with Spring Security, I am able to login, get the roles from the Active Directory server. However, after authenticating successfully, I am unable to access my main page and I don't understand from the log the reason.

Here is the section in my security.xml file related to this problem:

```
<http pattern='/resources/css/**' security="none" />
<http pattern='/resources/fonts/**' security="none" />
<http pattern='/resources/images/**' security="none" />
<http pattern='/resources/js/**' security="none" />

<http use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <!-- Limitation à une seule session utilisateur concurrente -->
    <session-management invalid-session-url="/identite?expiree=1">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/identite?expiree=1" />
    </session-management>

    <!-- Définitions pour le formulaire de la page JSP d'identification -->
    <form-login login-page="/identite" login-processing-url="/identite.proc" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/identite?err=1" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
    <csrf disabled="true" />

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/identite?termine=1" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

    <!-- Utiliser un canal chiffré pour les échanges -->
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/identite*" access="permitAll()" />
    <intercept-url requires-channel="https" pattern="/**" access="hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM')" />
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/erreur403" />
</http>
```

Here is the related section in the log after the authentication has been successfully completed until it reached the AccessDeniedException:

```
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.successfulAuthentication) [http-8443-1] Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AB7D98894DEA3BF993FB01DD845AE132; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.DefaultRedirectStrategy.sendRedirect) [http-8443-1] Redirecting to '/Atarget/' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper.saveContext) [http-8443-1] SecurityContext 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ce672a83: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AB7D98894DEA3BF993FB01DD845AE132; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme' stored to HttpSession: 'org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@6b38dba MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-1] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/css/**' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/fonts/**' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/images/**' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/resources/js/**' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ChannelProcessingFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/identite*' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Request '/' matched by universal pattern '/**' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.c.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-1] Request: FilterInvocation: URL: /; ConfigAttributes: [REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL] MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository.readSecurityContextFromSession) [http-8443-1] Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@ce672a83: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AB7D98894DEA3BF993FB01DD845AE132; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/logout' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /identite.proc MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter) [http-8443-1] SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AB7D98894DEA3BF993FB01DD845AE132; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-1] / at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.u.m.AntPathRequestMatcher.matches) [http-8443-1] Checking match of request : '/'; against '/identite*' MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-1] Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM')] MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired) [http-8443-1] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: AB7D98894DEA3BF993FB01DD845AE132; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM, SecRole-AdminSysteme MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-1] Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@4af08d0f, returned: -1 MDC{}
2015-04-16 15:18:03,851 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException) [http-8443-1] Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler MDC{}
```

It seems at some point my application is expecting my user to be anonymous and unauthenticated. I need some help to find why if this is the reason, otherwise I need some hints to investigate the appropriate parts of my configuration.

It seems related with the role validation. If I replace hasRole() by isAuthenticated() I can go further before hitting a hasRole() PreAuthorize condition that generates the same message.

How can I get more insight on what is going on with the role validation? My logging is at trace level.

I inserted a few lines of code into a servlet I changed the PreAuthorize annotation to isAuthenticated() in order to make it executes and log what is going on in. Here are my lines of code I added:

```
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String Welcome(HttpServletRequest requete, ModelMap model) {
    log.info("\t\tRoles connus:");
    for ( GrantedAuthority ga : SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities() ) {
        log.info("\t\t\t" + ga.getAuthority() + "\t" + requete.isUserInRole(ga.getAuthority()));
    }
    //Authentication auth = (Authentication) requete.getUserPrincipal();
    log.debug("The USER: " + requete.getRemoteUser());
(...)
```

And here is the output in the log:

```
2015-04-16 17:22:45,749 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-1] RunAsManager did not change Authentication object MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,765 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.ControleurCaissesDispo.Welcome) [http-8443-1]       Roles connus: MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,765 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.ControleurCaissesDispo.Welcome) [http-8443-1]           SecRole-Support-ABC true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,765 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.ControleurCaissesDispo.Welcome) [http-8443-1]           SecRole-Utilisateurs-ABC    true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,765 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1]          SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM   true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,765 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1]          SecRole-AdminSysteme    true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,781 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1]          Another_One true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,781 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1]          Another_Two true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,781 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1]          SoOn    true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,781 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1]          AndSoOn true MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,781 DEBUG (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1] The USER: myusername MDC{}
2015-04-16 17:22:45,781 INFO (c.d.g.w.c.CCD.Welcome) [http-8443-1] Session id: 1F1865F73F20A623DED099754B28AB11 MDC{}
```

At this point, the null defaultRolePrefix seems to work correctly since the roles where recognized by the servlet call. So, what is wrong with my   **@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM')")** annotation?

After reading this http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-method-security-in-web-context question 2.16 I am a bit puzzled. I am kind of new to Spring and I don't see where is my mistake. So, if someone can help, here is what I have in my web.xml:

```
<!-- Configuration du contexte applicatif Spring -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/security-applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <display-name>My App</display-name>
    <listener-class>com.company.gisti.web.myapp.ContexteApplicatifMyApp</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- MVC Filter -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/identite</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Filtres de sécurité -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- JSPs -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>403Jsp</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/403.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>403Jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/403</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Page d'erreur -->
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/erreur403</location>
</error-page>
```

Then in mvc-applicationContext.xml I have:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/theme_company/" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />   

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.gisti.web.myapp" />

</beans>
```

And the security-applicationContext.xml has already been posted above.

And finally what I have in my log:

```
2015-04-17 09:57:11,548 INFO (o.s.s.c.SpringSecurityCoreVersion.performVersionChecks) [main] You are running with Spring Security Core null MDC{}
2015-04-17 09:57:11,548 INFO (o.s.s.c.SecurityNamespaceHandler.<init>) [main] Couldn't determine package version information. MDC{}
2015-04-17 09:57:11,580 INFO (o.s.s.c.m.GlobalMethodSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.parse) [main] Expressions were enabled for method security but no SecurityExpressionHandler was configured. All hasPermision() expressions will evaluate to false. MDC{}
2015-04-17 09:57:11,642 INFO (o.s.s.c.h.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser.parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap) [main] Creating access control expression attribute 'permitAll()' for /identite* MDC{}
2015-04-17 09:57:11,642 INFO (o.s.s.c.h.FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceParser.parseInterceptUrlsForFilterInvocationRequestMap) [main] Creating access control expression attribute 'isAuthenticated()' for /** MDC{}
2015-04-17 09:57:11,659 INFO (o.s.s.c.h.HttpSecurityBeanDefinitionParser.checkFilterChainOrder) [main] Checking sorted filter chain: [Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 200, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 300, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 500, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 700, <org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0>, order = 1100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1600, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 1700, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2000, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2100, Root bean: class [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null, order = 2200, <org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0>, order = 2300] MDC{}
```

The third message is clear about the problem. However, why the first and second messages? What is missing my version of Spring Security Core cannot be determined? I am using Maven to manage dependencies, I looked at the directory and the libraries seems to the right version, I don't see if it is something missing in my namespace since the versions are also reported there. Is the third message related to the fact it cannot determine the version of Spring Security Core or it is two independant problems?

NOTE: I corrected the role in my description. As explained in my answer below, both roles exist and I had an OR condition which I removed and kept the wrong role to explain my problem. To avoid any further confusion, I even changed everything in my annotation to just pick one single role Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']] (from the log). To summarize, this was not the problem.

---

I added to my security-applicationContext.xml the following bean to set the role prefix and even if I changed it to 'none', '', 'PHILEMON_' or whatever, it seems it has absolutely no effect.

```
<b:bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <b:property name="rolePrefix" value="">
</b:property>
```

---

**Update 2015-04-20 11:35:**

Here is the log output where the access is denied while everything else says the user should be granted access. The RoleVoter return -1 despite the fact the user is actually having the role.

```
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter) [http-8443-2] /telechargement reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-2] Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.companyX.gisti.web.app.ControleurCD.TraitementTelechargement(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException; target is of class [com.companyX.gisti.web.app.ControleurCD]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']] MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation) [http-8443-1] Secure object: ReflectiveMethodInvocation: public java.lang.String com.companyX.gisti.web.app.ControleurCD.TraitementTelechargement(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.ui.ModelMap) throws javax.servlet.ServletException,java.io.IOException; target is of class [com.companyX.gisti.web.app.ControleurCD]; Attributes: [[authorize: 'hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM')', filter: 'null', filterTarget: 'null']] MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired) [http-8443-2] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: C8D81A8CF479F9DD2C789AB37DA6CFAF; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.i.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.authenticateIfRequired) [http-8443-1] Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@ce672a83: Principal: org.springframework.security.ldap.userdetails.LdapUserDetailsImpl@644dcdae: Dn: CN=MYUSERNAME,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=fsapps,DC=companyX,DC=uni; Username: myusername; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; CredentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: C8D81A8CF479F9DD2C789AB37DA6CFAF; Granted Authorities: SecRole-Support-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-DDMI, SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-2] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@69af0fcf, returned: -1 MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-1] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreInvocationAuthorizationAdviceVoter@69af0fcf, returned: -1 MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-2] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@2dcc5af0, returned: 0 MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-1] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@2dcc5af0, returned: 0 MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-1] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@43665a0d, returned: 0 MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.a.v.AffirmativeBased.decide) [http-8443-2] Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@43665a0d, returned: 0 MDC{}
2015-04-20 11:33:05,926 DEBUG (o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter.handleSpringSecurityException) [http-8443-2] Access is denied (user is not anonymous); delegating to AccessDeniedHandler MDC{}
```

---

**Update 2015-04-20 16:35:**

How can I check the userdetails to make sure everything is as expected? It looks like something related to the role prefix, however the output in the log never shows anything about the prefixes even if I am explicitly creating the beans for the security expression handler with a default role prefix and the role voter with a role prefix, it is like nothing happens. How can I gain some insight on what is going on? The hasRole() clause doesn't work neither if I move it from a PreAuthorize annotation to a url intercept filter. Only the isAuthenticated() seems to work. Is it something with the way Ldap/ActiveDirectory build the userdetails? I am about to throw all that stuff in the garbage can and write my own simple security system for this application. I am out of ideas.

---

**Update 2015-04-20 22:14:**

I solved my problem and the solution is not trivial. I will post the details as soon as possible for the records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what is wrong with my
>   @PreAuthorize("hasRole('SecRole-Administrateur-HPAM')") annotation?

Nothing wrong with your annotation but if you carefully monitor the log for roles for the logged in user. There is no role `SecRole-Administrateur-HPAM` only the following available.

```
SecRole-Support-ABC 
SecRole-Utilisateurs-ABC
SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM         
SecRole-AdminSysteme   
Another_One          
Another_Two           
SoOn             
AndSoOn
```

Please check your roles.

Comment: Ok, you got me. I made a mistake. Since my PreAuthorize was having a or condition and another hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM') entry, I removed the wrong one in order to simplify the description. Actually, you have both roles, my testing user is having one of these and my PreAuthorize was in fact asking for one OR the other as follow:

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('SecRole-Utilisateurs-HPAM') or hasRole('SecRole-Administrateur-HPAM')")

I will fix the wrong role in the original post.